# why my prog can not recognize the pronic number?

Tags: c, for-loop, numbers, logic

Why can't my program recognize a pronic number?

```
int main()
{
    int n , i , c;
    printf("hello this prog can recognize pronic number\n\n");
    printf("please enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d" , &n);
    for (i=1 ; i<=n ; i++)
    {
        c = n / i ;
    }

    if (c==i+1)
    {
        printf("this number is  a pronic number");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("this number is NOT pronic number");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look hard at that loop, as written it is equivalent to being completely replaced with single statement `c = 1;` Your algorithm is just wrong. Review what a pronic number is, and the research how to calculate one, then set it to code and *debug* it.

Comment: Hint: it is possible to determine whether a number is pronic without using any loops.  It is also possible to determine whether a number is pronic using only addition and comparison (but then you do need a loop).

Comment: Realise here that you are talking to software developers, not mathematicians. You would gain a larger audience if you perhaps explained what a pronic number was, because the concept is simple, but may not be familiar to your audience. That said, having looked it up, there is a far simpler solution : is_pronic = floor(√n).ceil(√n) == n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You evaluate the value of `c` only after the loop ends. You should check `c` as you go, and break out of the loop if you find the number to be a pronic number.

Note also that you're performing integer division, so you may find `c==i+1`, but `c*i` won't be equal to `n`:

```
int pronic = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i * (i + 1) == n) {
        printf("%d is a pronic number.\n", n);
        pronic = 1;
        break;
    }
}

if (!pronic) {
    printf("%d is not a pronic number\n", n);
}
```